# c++ how does friend function differs in memory location?

Tags: c++, friend-function

I am trying to understand how defining a function as a `friend function` impact its placement in memory (RAM).

For example, each class has a table of all of its methods and functions. Also, virtual functions are placed in the `vtable`.

**Where does `friend` functions belong?**

The reason I'm concerned, is due to a [recursion] function that has been invoked a large number of times via multiple threads in my c++ code, and eventually I'm getting *"v'table corruption runtime exception"*. which is a sign of memory corruption ([as I saw here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/848966/Find-the-place-for-crash-due-to-override-of-the-vt) for example).

Also, when declaring this function as a regular outside-of-class function, the exception persists.

When declaring that function to be `friend` however (it's a bad design, but for the sake of experiment), that exception no longer pops-up.

Therefor my question about friend functions' memory location.

Comment: *"each class has a table of all of its methods and functions"* - You say that based on what? There is no mention of it in the C++ standard.

Comment: Friend function is **not** a member function of the befriended class

Comment: *For example, each class has a table of all of its methods and functions.* Hmm, no. There's a vtable for virtual ones, but that's it.

Comment: @Borgleader And even then there might not be one.

Answer (score 9):

`friend` has nothing to do with where a compiler, linker or runtime loader puts the function, it's just a keyword that tells the compiler that the function can sidestep the visibility rules of the class.

Even if a `friend` function is defined inline in a class it's still considered a global non-member function.